# Using ikfast with 4DOF fails

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello List,

to get my arm working in moveit, I try to create the ikfast code for a 4DOF with the commands:

```
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada my_robot.urdf my_robot.dae
rosrun moveit_ikfast round_collada_numbers.py my_robot.dae my_robot_rounded.dae 5
python `openrave-config --python-dir`/openravepy/_openravepy_/ikfast.py --robot=my_robot_rounded.dae --iktype=translationxaxisangleznorm4d --baselink=1 --eelink=5 --savefile=ikf.cpp
```

This always fails. First there is a warning:

```
/usr/local/share/openrave-0.9/plugins/openravepy_configurationcache.so: libconfigurationcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But this file really exists!

Then at the end there is the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 2580, in matrix_multiply
raise ShapeError()  
sympy.matrices.matrices.ShapeError
```

I tried to make the urdf as simple as possible, it only consists of the needed links and joints.
The urdf-file can be found at [HERE](http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/my_robot.urdf)

I tried more complicated urdf's and they work.
I use ros-indigo and openrave-0.9 on ubuntu 14.04.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks in advance.

Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221972/using-ikfast-with-4dof-fails/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I generate my IKFast plugin for my manipulator, I must to install ROS Hydro for converting the URDF file to Collada, because Indigo didn't work.

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2016-02-02**:
Thanks for this workaround. I'll will try that.

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2016-02-03**:
converting URDF to collada worked for me without any problems.  I am running indigo igloo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS